# Lerna fails with 404 when trying to link dependency

Tags: lerna

My structure is as follows:

- package.json
- lerna.json
- packages

  - myproj-util

    - package.json
  - myproj-schema

    - package.json -- has dev-depenency on `myproj-util`

Neither project is published to npm yet.

When I run `lerna boostrap` I get:

```
❯ lerna bootstrap
lerna info version 2.4.0
lerna info versioning independent
lerna info Bootstrapping 2 packages
lerna info lifecycle preinstall
lerna info Installing external dependencies
lerna ERR! execute callback with error
lerna ERR! Error: Command failed: npm install
lerna ERR! npm ERR! code E404
lerna ERR! npm ERR! 404 Not Found: myproj-util@*
```

My understanding [from the docs](https://github.com/lerna/lerna#how-bootstrap-works) is that when running `lerna bootstrap` it should "check if each dependency is part of the Lerna repo" so it should just be symlinked.

So... why is it not just symlinking my internal dependency? The dependency is under `packages/` and the folder name and package name match exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line from the docs provides a hint:

> The **version** of babel-generator in the package.json of babel-core is satisfied by packages/babel-generator, passing for an internal dependency.

i.e., your internal packages have to match any version constraints otherwise they will be treated as external packages.

Even though my dependency was on `"myproj-util": "*"`, I had forgotten to add a version (any version) to the `package.json` of `myproj-util`. Simply adding the `version` fixed the problem. i.e., the `myproj-util` package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "myproj-util",
  "version": "0.1.0"
}
```

Comment: I have checked all my package.json file and they marry-up to the dependency version. I am not using a caret either. However, I still get a 404 cannot be found message :(

Answer (score 0):

I missed adding the package name to the `"workspaces"` key in the root `package.json`.

### package `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "database",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module"
  ...
}
```

### root `package.json`

```json
"workspaces": {
  "packages": [
    "database"
  ]
}
```